# center content uniformly using em's

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

Im having trouble using em's to center a custom radio button "tick" at the center of its parent.

It works well using px, but em's fail to center uniformly at certain sizes.
It misplaces the content by a few pixels and sometimes it seems quite random. E.g if i reload the page without changing anything in styles, it may sometimes render it correctly, and other times incorrectly.

Below is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.
( toggle ems/pixels and change the size to see the problem )

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/1k35tfgL/

```
<body>

    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="toggle" value="toggle em vs px"/>
    <input type="button" id="bigger" value="increace size"/>
    <input type="button" id="smaller" value="decrease size"/>
</body>

body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#parent {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;    
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 177, 172);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: white;
    margin: 20px;
}
#child {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    background: rgb(37, 177, 172);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#parent.em {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;    
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 177, 172);
    background: white;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
#parent.em #child {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0.46em;
    background: rgb(37, 177, 172);
    border-radius: 2em;
}

var size = 10;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#parent").toggleClass("em");
    });
     $("input#bigger").click(function() {
         size++;
         $("body").css("font-size", size);
    });
     $("input#smaller").click(function() {
        if ( size > 1 ) {size--;}
        $("body").css("font-size", size);
    });
});
```

Is there anything i could do to keep using em's and be sure it will always display evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems fine if you keep the same ratio for the circles on my quick test. For example, changing `.46em to .4em`, `2em to 2.4em`, `3em to 3.4em` which is the same as 24px and 34px using your base size.  Please remember that ems will round since you cannot have fractions of pixels.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/1k35tfgL/2/

Comment: Hi,
Your sample has the same problem as mine, if you reduce/increase the size once or twice, then it looks asymmetric  again.
I dont mind rounding, but i would like it to round evenly on all sides. Atm it rounds ... quite randomly. Elements that are clones of each other, look different, even though they are exactly the same in every way.

Comment: @RainerPlumer are you trying to keep that squarish look in the center?   Could it possibly be the `border-radius` that you are concerned about?  This causes the circle in the center to get more and more round on your pixel vs ems since one is based on the base while the other is fixed.

Comment: in one case all objects are in pixels, and after toggling all objects are in em's.
Border radius doesnt matter, you can remove that attribute and the issue remains, the inner object is centered asymmetrically.

Comment: @RainerPlumer I'm going to assume that I don't understand the question anymore.  which element are you trying to keep centered/uniformed?  I've edited your fiddle to show one as pixels and the other as ems and then increased the size and they seem to be identical for me on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/1k35tfgL/5/

Comment: They look uniform at most sizes, and most of the time, especially when scaled bigger, but at a bit smaller sizes...sizes i use for mobile devices, these differences kick in which in a neat orderly row, make the list look messy. Even if its just one or 2 px
Here is your example squares, and they look different, even though console says they should be identical. next to them there are buttons from my app, which are all clonse of the same element with exact same css rule and sizes. I would like all of the buttons to look like the one at the bottom. 
link to google doc image
http://goo.gl/UhHABz